# NGINX: How to write generic rewrite rules to match multiple url conditions

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to redirect the request from one website to other with multiple paths and random query parameter.

Example: I want to redirect all my requests coming on https://test.com/test to https://example.com. But there are multiple urls like

```
    https://test.com/test/path1/path2 ---> https://example.com/path1/path2
    https://test.com/test/path3/path4/path5?para1=val1&para2=val2 ---> https://example.com/path3/path4/path5?para1=val1&para2=val2
```

URL may contain different paths and different query parameter. To make it generic, I used logic like which doesn't work always.

```
location /test/{
  rewrite ^/test/(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

Can anyone suggest the correct way to handle this? Logic works well for first url but not for the second.
Also would like to know if it is possible to get the final formed url in logs.

Comment: The configuration snippet looks fine and should work for both example URLs, **only if** Nginx chooses this location to process the request. There are [rules](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) as to which location is chosen, but you could use `location ^~ /test/ { ... }` to avoid conflicting regular expression location blocks.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work always?

Comment: I was not having an access to the 3rd party application to check which url forms with above regex. But when I replaced that url and check, I found the query params are also going.

Comment: I am now getting problem with the header returned by the backend service. I am getting the Header in response when I call nginx but it doesn't show the correct value. Seems like nginx doing something with the header. How to return the same header value which we are getting from backend using nginx?